# Two URL's, same content, is this considered duplicate content by search engines?

Tags: seo

I've developed a service that allows users to search for stores on www.mysite.com.
I also have partners that uses my service. To the user, it looks like they are on my partners web site, when in fact they are on my site. I have only replaced my own header and footer, with my partners header and footer.

For the user, it looks like they are on `mysite.partner.com` when in reality they are on `partner.mysite.com`.

If you understood what I tried to explain, my question is:

Will Google and other search engines consider this duplicate content?

**Update - canonical page**
If I understand canonical pages correctly, `www.mysite.com` is my canonical page.

So when my partner uses `mysite.partner.com?store=wallmart&id=123` which "redirects" (CNAME) to `partner.mysite.com?store=wallmart&id=123`, my server recognize my sub-domain.

So what I need to do, is to dynamically add the following in my `<HEAD>` section:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="mysite.com?store=wallmart&id=123">
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's duplicate content but there is no penalty as such.

The problem is, for a specific search Google will pick one version of a page and filter out the others from the results. If your partner is targeting the same region then you are in direct competition.

The canonical tag is a way to tell Google which is the official version. If you use it then only the canonical page will show up in search results. So if you canonicalise back to your domain then your partners will be excluded from search results. Only your domains pages will ever show up. Not good for your partners.

There is no win. The only way your partners will do well is if they have their own content or target a different region and you don't do the canonical tag.

So your partners have a chance, I would not add the canonical. Then it's down to the Google gods to decide which of your duplicate pages gets shown.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer and clearing up the "penalty" question. I found this article that demystifies this a bit further: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.no/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html. The whole point for having partners is to increase the traffic to my site - so I'd rather have my links show up in Google than links to my partners sub-domains (which again is redirected to my site).

Comment: What's in it for your partners then?

Comment: They get a fantastic service for free which they can offer their readers and thus create more value. For smaller countries (like Scandinavian countries) fashion magazines often want exclusive rights to have this service on their webpage. There's more to it, but it kind of sums it up.

Comment: If your partners are international then there is a better chance they will rank in their own regions, while you rank in yours. That would work well.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. You'll want to use canonical tagging to stop this happening.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question. Is my understanding of canonical page correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will be considered as duplicate content by Google. Cause you have replaced only footer and header. By recent Google algorithm, content should be unique for website or even blog. If content is not unique, your website will be penalized by Google.

Comment: @wetempaltenow, any suggestion to solve my problem would be nice :)

Comment: @Steven, You need to change content as I told you before. So you also need to change body part of website with header and footer. Another is canonical which you already know.